# How to choose correct image size for HTML background?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am planning to use an image as my web-page background:

```
html {
    background:#505D6E url(/img/body7.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

What should be the image size? Would 1920×1280px be enough? Or, should I use some other size? Or, probably I should define different image sizes depending on user's device? If so, how could I do it?

Comment: Its enough since the image is large in size and background-size is cover.

Answer (score 1):

You should use media queries to load different size images for different devices. e.g., there's no need to load a 1080p image on a phone. Here's a simple implementation:

```
body{
    background-color:#505D6E;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(/img/body7-maxres.jpg);
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 1920px){
    body{ background-image: url(/img/body7-1080p.jpg); }
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    body{ background-image: url(/img/body7-sm.jpg); }
}
```

Media query docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: The smallest image should be defined outside of media queries, just to make sure no incompatible browser will load more data than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger the image, the longer it will take to load your page.

You could indeed use CSS media queries, so that your user only loads the image that fits his viewport size.

Further explanation: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en

> Media queries enable us to create a responsive experience, where specific styles are applied to small screens, large screens and anywhere in between. The media query syntax allows for the creation of rules that can be applied depending on device characteristics.